# shadcn components not styling correctly in a node module

Tags: typescript, npm, tailwind-css

I have a react component that uses tailwindcss and shadcn components that I'm packaging up and dsitributing as an NPM module. I'm running into an error when I use the NPM module in a demo project that it doesn't render the shadcn components. It does render just fine in storybook.

For ex. this is what it looks like in storybook (this is correct)

[storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLA3R.png)

And this is what it renders when I use the module in a demo project.

```
import NeoCron from "neocron";
import "neocron/dist/src/globals.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <div>
        <NeoCron inputText="Set a schedule" selectorText="Run every" />
      </div>
  );
}
```

[demo-prject-no-styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeroq.png)

I'm bundling the shadcn components in the dist folder along with my globals.css file in the NPM module.

[dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSAYD.png)

Any thoughts on how I can get the shadcn components to render correctly in the demo project?

here is my package.json file:

````
  "name": "neocron",
  "version": "0.1.7",
  "private": false,
  "main": "dist/src/Neocron.js",
  "export": "dist/src/Neocron.js",
  "types": "dist/src/Neocron.d.ts",
  "description": "A lightweight, modern chron editor",
  "files": [
    "dist/src"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && cp src/globals.css dist/src/globals.css",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check .",
    "prettier:write": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "jq": "^1.7.2",
    "lucide-react": "^0.277.0",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.2",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.1",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/node": "20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "storybook": "^7.4.2",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}```
````